# Translate command line to code from Openssl to c++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a command line for OpenSSL :

```
openssl pkeyutl -inkey private.key -sign -in b64.dat -pkeyopt digest:SHA256 -out result.dat
```

That I want to code using C++ and OpenSSL libraries. 
For CURL there is an instruction such as `--libcurl code.c` and it outputs the equivalent code in C for the given commands which is a great time saver.

Is there such a thing in OpenSSL? And if there isn't, what's the equivalent of this command?

Comment: If you want to build it yourself, perhaps the free [OpenSSL Cookbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html) would be a good place to start and then continue by [cloning the source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) for openssl and just follow what it does for that specific command.

Comment: Will try this right away.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign an already hashed string we can use `EVP_PKEY_sign`;
The private key here must be a string with the decrypted private key in PEM format.

The result is written in a file result.dat which we can `base64 result.dat` (in linux) to obtain a valid signature.

```
RSA* createPrivateRSA(std::string key) {
  RSA *rsa = NULL;
  const char* c_string = key.c_str();
  BIO * keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)c_string, -1);
  if (keybio==NULL) {
      return 0;
  }
  rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
  return rsa;
}

void sellar(std::string hashclear, std::string privateKey_string){

  EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
  /* md is a SHA-256 digest in this example. */
  unsigned char *sig;
  size_t siglen;

  unsigned char clear_message[hashclear.length()];
  strcpy((char*) clear_message,hashclear.c_str());
  size_t mdlen;
  // //1. Decodificar hashclear. || base64 -d data.dat > b64.dat -> Me debe dar una cadena de 32 bytes.
  unsigned char * md = base64_decode(clear_message, strlen((char*) clear_message), &mdlen);
  std::cout << "MD is " << mdlen << " bytes long.\n";
  // //2. Cargar llave privada.
  RSA* privateRSA = createPrivateRSA(privateKey);
  EVP_PKEY* signing_key  = EVP_PKEY_new();

  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(signing_key, privateRSA);

  ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(signing_key, NULL /* no engine */);
  if(!ctx) {
    std::cout << "Error CTX_new" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  if (EVP_PKEY_sign_init(ctx) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error sign_init\n";
    return;
  }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error set_rsa_padding\n";
    return;
 }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error set_signature_md\n";
    return;
 }

 /* Determine buffer length */
 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, NULL, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error PKEY_sign\n";
    return;
 }
 sig = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(siglen);

 if (!sig){
    std::cout << "Error malloc";
    return;
 }

 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, sig, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error sign";
    return;
 }
 std::cout << siglen << " bytes written in buffer sig\n";
 /* Signature is siglen bytes written to buffer sig */
 size_t cadena_sellada_len;
 unsigned char * cadena_sellada = base64_encode(sig, siglen, &cadena_sellada_len);

 std::ofstream myfile ("result_final.dat");
 if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    for(int count = 0; count < cadena_sellada_len; count ++){
        myfile << cadena_sellada[count] ;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is there such a thing  in OpenSSL?

Yes there is like libssl and  libcrypto (with platform specific naming) like used in [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) itself - but as I understand you it will be better to use a c++ prepared library like [this](https://github.com/oyefremov/libcryptoplus) if you like to do it right.

> And if there isn't, what's the equivalent of this command?

Also yes - if I understand you right you are searching something like that:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main () 
{ 

    system("openssl pkeyutl -inkey private.key -sign -in b64.dat -pkeyopt digest:SHA256 -out result.dat"); //in one line
    return 0; 
}
```

"System" translate a c++ string into bash code in the terminal its started from and works very well.

I hope that helps you :) If you need further assistance for the first example I can edit my post - just leave me a comment on what you need.

*Also please don't forget check your Question as solved if you got a proper answer to avoid it showing up in the "unsolved" section of stackoverflow.com ;)*

Comment: Whilst this would solve the issue, I'm looking for a way to do it without calling the OS.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that. If you do a git project I am happy to work with you on solving the problem since I was fiddeling a bit myself on it and as I looked into it I didn't found an easy api for accessing openssl directly for an easy access.


The guys are fast with downvoting and slow with upvoting, holy god - your question got at least an upvote form me :D